# How do you slow down a sine function when t moves between 0 and 1

Tags: trigonometry

I am making a shader that renders rainbow colors and am using `abs(sin(t))` function for each of the RGB values to select the color, where `t` is the time in milliseconds. The issue is that `t` moves between 0 and 1 every 1 second, and then immediately resets to 0, which is much too fast for what I am making. If I try to slow down the sine function with `sin(t/2)` then this will only ever use values between 0-0.5, and thus does not provide the full spectrum of RGB color values that I need.

I have no control over the time value currently. So my question is, is there a way I can slow this sin function down while still starting at a value of `t=0` and ending at a value of `t=1`?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking for : (1) If you have no control over the "speed" of sin function, then it will always be as fast as it is now ! (2) If you want to generate more values between 0.0 & 1.0, then you can increase "Polling" rate to eg 0.00 & 1.00 ! (3) If you want to vary the input t (eg linearly or non-linearly) , then you may not get sin function but get something else like sin(t^2) or in general sin(f(t)) ! (4) It is not clear why you must use sin function only (5) It would make thing more clear if you give a table of t values & "Potentially" wanted output values !

Comment: @Prem I am create a GLSL shader which "ticks" 20 times per second. the shader includes this time value in the form of values between 0.00 - 1.00 starting at 0.00 and reaching 1.00 after 1 second or 20 ticks, at which point it resets back to 0. The issue is that I want my rainbow animations to start and end at the same place, not jump cut after 1 second. If I slow down the sine function like how I mentioned, it causes the color values to "jump cut" instead of flowing back to the start color. Im not sure if there is another way other than sin or cos as I am new to shaders in general

Comment: If you get 20 "ticks" out of the Shader , then that is all you get & thus you get to generate 20 values. You should use some alternative to sin to get more coverage : ( Alternative 1 "linear" ) use f(t)=1-abs(t-10)/10 ( Alternative 2 "non-linear" ) use f(t)=1-abs(t-10)^2/100 [[ Both Alternatives give 0.0 at the start (t=0) & then go to 1.0 in the middle (t=10) & then drop to 0.0 at the end (t=20) without "jump cuts" ]] I hope I am "Interpreting" your Question Correctly !!!

Comment: @Perm easy on the !  It makes it hard to concentrate when you shout!!!

Comment: Is 20 ticks fixed, why not 1000 to slow it down?

Comment: About the 20 ticks , I had earlier suggested the same **[ (2) If you want to generate more values between 0.0 & 1.0, then you can increase "Polling" rate to eg 0.00 & 1.00 ]** but OP says that is set by Shader. I would look into Configurations to change it, but not sure about OP Environment. I would also look into treating multiple cycles as one big cycle by having "MOC = My Own Counter" which ticks up on every Shader tick & gets reset at MOC = 200 or some such limit @Paul

Comment: @RTT - Do you want your colors to cycle more slowly, or do you want the cycle to "close up", i.e. change continuously and have the same value at 0.0 and 1.0? Because these are completely different questions. (My answer below addressed what you asked in your question, not what you put in your comment."

Comment: @RTT - I've downvoted your question until you clarify - in the body of the question , not just in comments - which you want.

Answer (score 1):

Discussion in comments makes me think that you have 3 Main Alternatives to Mix&Match:

(1) Choose some other function Eg:
$f(t)=1-|t-10|/10$ "Linear" triangular wave with Peak at t=10
$f(t) = 1- |t-10|^2/100$ "Non-Linear" wave with Peak at t=10
Here, the function f starts with 0.0 at t=0 , goes to Peak 1.0 at t=10 , then comes back to 0.0 at t=20 , where t is the original tick.

(2) Choose some other "Polling" rate Eg:
$t=0.00, 0.01, 0.02, \cdots , 0.99 , 1.00$ , where t is the original tick
You might have to Check the Shader Documentation to figure out the Configuration Variables.

(3) Choose some other Period of the Cycle Eg:
Take multiple Periods of the Shader into one large Period.
Start with $T=0$ & Increment this on each Shader tick t to get $1,2,3,4, \cdots , 199, 200$ , where t is the original tick & T is Your Own Tick Counter.
When T is 200, then at the next tick, reset it to 0.
Use this T in your function, to get a slow output.

(4) Choose a Combination of these Alternatives Eg:
Use a linear function with Increased Polling rate while taking multiple Periods into one large Period.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer, sadly, is "No".

If

- you get the exact same value of $t$ at 1.56 seconds into your run and at 2.56 seconds into your run, and
- your color can only depend on the value of $t$.

then the colors displayed between (T = 2 seconds and T = 3 seconds) will be identical to the colors displayed between (T = 1 seconds and T = 2 seconds). [I'm using capital 'T' to count the total number of seconds from program start (including fractions of a second), as you seem to already use lower case 't' for the value that wraps around.]

You can monkey around with how quickly you move through various parts of that one second cycle (try using $t^3$ or $t^{1/3}$ in place of $t$, to move faster or slower during the first part of the one-second cycle).

But if you want two one-second slices to look different from each other, you're going to need a way to persist a value between successive calls to your shader. This is now a programming question, not a math question.